# Is it possible to save a "preferred view" to the default view?

Tags: xcode, view, settings

I'm essentially creating a settings page which will call up different views (using different color schemes) but I cant figure out how to save a view as the default view once the user selects it.  Any ideas regarding this or a more efficient way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Under Project settings -> Summary -> There should be a "Main Interface" drop down and from there you can select the Default View. Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to do this by having a button in the application for the user to press and decide which is the main window?

Comment: I don't know about that. I don't believe Apple likes developers changing the app's screen orders for security reasons.

Comment: Hmm Ok. So you have any suggestions for doing what I would like to do?  Thanks for your help!